# How to append results to dataframes given an operation whose result is the size of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that describes the trajectory of a set of particles:

```
t = 
                  y            x          mass  ...        ep  frame  particle
0         19.786517  1000.656583   8673.042534  ...  0.078461      0         0
376     1424.723047   216.250029  14354.289353  ...  0.108937      0         1
375     1426.538703  1564.423771  11674.833112  ...  0.130680      0         2
374     1428.278151  2018.516185  18706.219367  ...  0.075380      0         3
373     1426.137787   626.417419  20111.330551  ...  0.060769      0         4
            ...          ...           ...  ...       ...    ...       ...
750968   717.455045   170.929977  12260.771171  ...  0.027305   1364      2896
750967   718.018964   926.256111  14161.143811  ...  0.019303   1364      5743
750966   709.771559   239.818120  17578.233781  ...  0.018574   1364      6599
750980   758.318235  1232.281636   7943.370072  ...  0.041535   1364      6228
751327  2029.563012  1472.951389  11750.935891  ...  0.051639   1364      6253

[751328 rows x 10 columns]
```

Given that I want to study the Kinematics of this system, I developed a class that given the dataframe of a single particle (e.g. particle 2), it gives back a new dataframe with new properties (e.g. speed, angle ...), derived from a scipy fitting model and added to the particle's dataframe.

```py
gb = t.groupby('particle')
p2_df = gb.get_group(2)

PK = Particle_Kinematics(p2_df, n= 0.5)
PK_df = PK.to_df()
```

Therefore:

```py
PK_df.columns = ['y', 'x', 'mass', ..., 'v_y', 'v_x', 'v', 'angle']
```

Is there a pythonic way to construct a new particles' dataframe from applying my class to all particles?

I went through the documentation of the `GroupBy` object and can't see how aggregation or transformation could do the job.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to iterate over each unique particle ID and apply the `Particle_Kinematics(particle_group, n=0.5)` ?

Comment: Show the code for your class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class doesn't do any aggregation of the grouped data but just adds new columns for each row in the group. You can just do the below changes to make it work and return the full dataframe

```
def some_dummy_function(df):
  df['new_col'] = df['particle'].mean()*2
  return df

df.groupby('particle').apply(some_dummy_function)
```